# axios async await function not returning validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, react-native, axios

```html
export const register = (user, callback, errorback) => async dispatch => {
  try{

    let response = await axios.post(`${PINGUIN_ROOT_URL}/users/create`, user)

    if (response.data.auth_token){
      auth_token = response.data.auth_token
      dispatch({ type: REGISTER_SUCCESS, payload: auth_token})
      callback()
    } else {
      let error = response
      throw error
    }

  }catch(error){

    dispatch({type: REGISTER_FAIL})
    errorback()

  }
```

Hi, I am building a login register based off of what we have learned. It works but for some reason the error validations wont come back. I built a rails api and I see the validation errors when I use postman but when I try to get the errors back using redux the register function above gets to the "let response = .." line and immediately goes to the catch(error) line. I dont know how to pass back the actual validation errors that I see when I use post man because the error that is being caught is the following:

```html
Error: Request failed with status code 422
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:538)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:381)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:485
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:181)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:250)
    at MessageQueue.js:101
```

Now again, the code is working when it actually logs in the user however it fails to actually give me the validation errors that I need. I see the validation errors comming back as json in postman but i do not get to see them in practice. Help please?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the response object from your error object as `error.response`

```
try{
    let response = await axios.post(`${PINGUIN_ROOT_URL}/users/create`, user)
    ...
  } catch(error){
    console.error(error.response)
}
```